# FirebaseArray doesn't update View

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

First of all I want to make a plunkr for this but code is so complex and reproducing this may cost a lots of time.

But I am gonna attach pictures about this problem.

**Problem is:**

Data is coming perfectly from database, and its assigning the data to array but somehow view is not updating.

1. I have an array of objects. So i used firebaseArray for this.

This is my first array

[image: Array]

2. I am checking data on `Console.Log` and its coming, its changing... `$timeout`, `setTimeout` doesn't working...

   var ref = firebase.database().ref("live");
    var liveData = $firebaseArray(ref);

*EXAMPLE CHANGED EVENT:*

```
          ref.child("events").on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
          // CHANGE EVENTS
          var changedData = snapshot.val();

          angular.forEach(liveData[0], function(i,v) {
            if (angular.isObject(i)) {
              if (i.id == changedData.id) {
                $timeout(function() {
                i = changedData;
                console.log(i);
                console.log("1 event has been changed");
                }, 100);
              }
            }
          });
          });
```

I am new and this is my first project with **Firebase&AngularFire**.

Maybe I did something wrong, maybe I am doing all wrong but I don't know what...

BTW this is service not controller, I am not/can not using SCOPE.

This data is so complex, I am gonna show you our view so you can understand better..

```
  <div ng-repeat="tournament_id in sport.tournaments track by $index"
     ng-if="(live.data.tournaments[tournament_id] && live.isCollapsed('sports', sport.id))">
    <div class="main-box">
        <h4 class="tournament-name" ng-click="live.manageCollapse('tournaments', tournament_id)">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up {{live.storage.tournaments[tournament_id].style}}"></i>
            {{live.data.tournaments[tournament_id].name}} ({{live.data.tournaments[tournament_id].event_count}})
        </h4>
        <div ng-if="live.isCollapsed('tournaments', tournament_id)">
            <table class="table">
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a local variable in your callback function. Try `liveData[0][v] = changedData`.

Note: Swapping `i` and `v` may be better. i stands for index, v stands for value.